# How do I automatically add spacing between divs without using percentage?

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs aligned horizontally.
How do I make the spacing between them automatic so that if I resize the screen or add another div, there will be equal spacing between divs.

Example when screen width is 600px:

[image: This is an image description]

Example when screen width is 330px:

[image]

Hopefully my explanation is good enough.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could use flexbox and the `justify-content` property. See my answer here for options and details: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items along the Main Axis](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Flexbox** can do that https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/210/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
  <div class="box">Box</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around; 
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    background: black;
    padding: 25px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't realize you could do that with flex boxes, I thought you could only make the width of element auto change. I'll accept the answer unless there is an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find a solution with flexbox:

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.item {
    background:#000;
    height:50px;
    width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

More information about using flexbox you can find here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfect answer but already got an answer which worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexboxes, just appy these proprieties to the container of divs:

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: oops, I didn't see thath Marcin had already answered in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `inline-block` + `text-align:justify;` for older browser generating an extra last invisible line with `:after`, or `flex` + `justify-content:space-betwween;`

```css
.ib {
text-align:justify;
  }
.ib:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:99%;
  }
.flex {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  }
.d100 {
  width:100px;
  height:2em;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="ib">
  <div class="d100"></div>
  <div class="d100"></div>
  <div class="d100"></div>
  </div>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="d100"></div>
  <div class="d100"></div>
  <div class="d100"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flex` declaration - see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: This will flexibly change the width of the div, but I want the div width to stay  the same, just the spacing/margin to change based on how many elements and the screen size. EDIT: I didn't fully understand what you were telling me, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  flexboxes, this solustion is for IE 10+ and latest other browsers.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Add a border thats the same color as background

Option 2: add a background colored div and set display to inline

Comment: I need the spacing/padding to change if the screen gets resized.

Comment: Another option is do what i said with bootstrap

Comment: or use the bootstrap colums