# Center divs in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex and I am trying to achieve something. There are 5 divs shown in the code. In min-width:768px I want the fourth and the fifth div to be centered. Can anyone help me? Here is the code:

*css*

```
.row{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  @media  (min-width:576px){
    .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 33%;
      flex: 0 0 33%;
      max-width: 33%;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 19%;
      flex: 0 0 19%;
      max-width: 19%;
    }
  }
```

**html**

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col"><p>first</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>second</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>third</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>fourth</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>fifth</p>  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Add `justify-content: center;` to your `.row` class in your CSS

Comment: thank you!! and do you know how can I add a space between divs?

Comment: add some margins maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Comment: @JensW I meant can we use anything from flex

Comment: @Arianna22 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984424/how-do-i-automatically-add-spacing-between-divs-without-using-percentage check out this thread maybe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this in your media query:

```
  @media (min-width: 768px){
    .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 19%;
      flex: 0 0 19%;
      max-width: 19%;
    }

    .col:nth-child(4),
    .col:nth-child(5){
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your code I have correct it. you just work with little bit of css

```
 .row{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: center;
  }
  .col {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  }
  @media  (min-width:576px){
      .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 19%;
      flex: 0 0 19%;
      max-width: 19%;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 768px){


    .col {
      -ms-flex: 0 0 33%;
      flex: 0 0 33%;
      max-width: 33%;
    }
  }




 <div class="row">
  <div class="col"><p>first</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>second</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>third</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>fourth</p>  </div>
  <div class="col"><p>fifth</p>  </div>  
</div>
```